# Is there any ways to set tabindex in recaptcha 2?

Tags: recaptcha, tabindex

I have a custom form with several text fields. All of these elements have a `tabindex` value set. But once I placed the new recaptcha am not able to access the checkbox as it has tabindex set to default 0. Is there any way to set tab index for the new captcha checkbox ?

The following code demonstrates the issue:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" tabindex="1" autofocus>
    <input type="password" name="password" tabindex="2">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="[SITE KEY]"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" tabindex="4">
</form>
```

Note the `<script>` is from the `<head>`.

When tabbing through the form, the order is as follows:

- username
- password
- submit button
- captcha

The desired order is as follows:

- username
- password
- captcha
- submit button

Comment: I'm not having any issues tabbing through input elements with `tabindex` set through to the reCAPTCHA 2. Can the OP or @Mooseman create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara There's no way to embed the captcha without using a site key. I will post the code without the key though.

Comment: `setTimeout(function()
{ $('.g-recaptcha iframe').attr('tabindex', '2') }, 200)`

Comment: So glad I read the comments @user345426 has a workable solution, just call `$('.g-recaptcha iframe').attr('tabindex', '6')` on load

Comment: Glad you like it :-)  Can't believe Google does not post this on their docs page. SMH

Answer (score 6):

I spent a fair amount of time debugging the reCAPTCHA 2 API yesterday looking for undocumented features, and I'm reasonably certain Google does not provide an API to do this.

However, all you need to do is set the `tabindex` attribute on the `iframe` elements that gets generated. Google sets it to `0` by default, but there is no reason we can't change it. The `iframe` does not get generated immediately, so you will need to wait for it to render first.

Also, it would be nice if we could specify the `tabindex` we want on the `.g-recaptcha` element, in an attribute like `data-tabindex`.

Here is a nice little snippet that does just that, looping over the `.g-recaptcha`, adding an event listener for the `iframe` for the `load` event (using the capture phase since the event will not bubble), and setting the `tabIndex` property of the `iframe` to the value of the `data-attribute` attribute. Just include this script in the footer of you webpage, or run it on document ready.

```
//Loop over the .g-recaptcha wrapper elements.
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('g-recaptcha'), function(element) {
    //Add a load event listener to each wrapper, using capture.
    element.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
        //Get the data-tabindex attribute value from the wrapper.
        var tabindex = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-tabindex');
        //Check if the attribute is set.
        if (tabindex) {
            //Set the tabIndex on the iframe.
            e.target.tabIndex = tabindex;
        }
    }, true);
});
```

And in your HTML, include the `data-tabindex` value you want.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="[SITE KEY]" data-tabindex="3">
```

Comment: Something is still getting tabbed to between the password field and the captcha checkbox. Can this be avoided?

Comment: @Mooseman What browser? Some browser seem to tab to the iframe itself, then the content. I don't think this can be avoided.

Comment: Chrome 40. The hyperlinks also get tabbed, but I don't believe that's avoidable, being inside the iframe.

Comment: @Mooseman Yeah, there's some off-screen `<div id="recaptcha-accessible-status" class="rc-anchor-aria-status" aria-live="assertive" tabindex="0">` element. Not sure what it is. I can't think of anything to do about that one, but for skipping the links you could use [`data-callback`](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param) with a global function name that will set the focus to the next element in the form on success.

Comment: Able to use `data-callback`, but would still like to avoid the extra tab between the password input and the checkbox. A hacky solution for this would be acceptable.

Comment: @Mooseman I'm afraid same-origin policy renders a hacky solution impossible.

Comment: I've awarded you the bounty. I do, however, hope Google offers a more robust API in the future.

Answer (score 2):

In new version of recaptcha you can use data-tabindex.
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param
something like this:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="[SITE KEY]" data-tabindex="[Custom tabindex]"></div>
```

or this one:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" tabindex="1" autofocus>
    <input type="password" name="password" tabindex="2">
    <div class="g-recaptcha"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" tabindex="4">
</form>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<script>
    var onloadCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render(document.querySelector(".g-recaptcha"), {
            'sitekey' : 'your site key',
            'tabindex' : 'custom tabindex',
        });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Have you testing this solution? I apparently do not get to tab through the reCAPTCHA at all... it just skips it on my end.It could also be that it does not work on my specific browser (SeaMonkey)...